# Custom Google Contacts list view in Xiaomi Mi4i

Tags: google-contacts, miui, contact-groups, xiaomi

I am an Indian residing in the UK, and the phone is bought in India.

Phone Model: Xiaomi Mi4i
Android Version: 5
MIUI Version: 6

---

**Problem**

I am an avid user of Google and I have my contact lists grouped this way in Google:

- My Contacts
- UK Friends
- India Friends
- Stack Overflow
- Directors
- Phone Contacts

As everyone know, the contacts can co-exist i.e., if Praveen is found in UK Friends, it can also be found in Phone Contacts. What I have done is, the group Phone Contacts has all the contacts that are supposed to be displayed in the phone, and currently I am using my Lava Iris 504Q phone, that shows my contacts in Custom View, where it displays only the contacts from Google (Account) » Phone Contacts (Group).

Currently using my Lava Mobile, what I can do is:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

1. **Step 1:** Open the Contacts App. Tap the menu and tap on **Contacts to Display**.

   [image: IMG: Open the Contacts App]
2. Select **Customize** from the next menu, that displays all the Accounts that are configured in the phone.

   [image: IMG: Customize option]
3. The **Define Custom View** screen appears and again it shows all the Accounts that are configured in the phone.

   [image: IMG: Define Custom View]
4. This view provides me a checkbox view, where I choose to display whichever contact group from any account that is configured on this phone.

   [image: IMG: Checkbox view]

Is the problem understandable? Can this be sorted out?

But this process is not there in my new phone. Currently I have:

- See the order of images as **Step 1** → **Step 2 → Step 3**:

  <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

  [image: IMG: Step 1]
  [image: IMG: Step 2]
  [image: IMG: Step 3]

**References**

The best reference for this issue I could find is on the [MIUI Forums](http://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/question-about-google-contacts.19748/). The other reference for the custom contact view is [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30761/android-limit-contacts-displayed-contacts-book/).

Comment: Hi Praveen! I edited your question and shortened the length of it because it was  long to follow because of images. In case you find the edit unjust, feel free to rollback. :)

Comment: @Firelord No problem. It looks better now!

Comment: Any updates? `:)`